# Update row according to result number in result set

Tags: mysql

I am looking to do the following:

```
tblOne:
-page_id
-split



tblMany
-view_id
-page_id
```

I want to order tblOne by the number of related page_id in tblMany.

Then divide the number of rows in tblOne by 5 and update tblOne.split to a number between 1 - 5 into which split it falls... e.g if there are 50 rows... row 0 - 9 are split 1, 10 - 19 split 2...etc

I am sure I can do the 'count' part... but havn't a clue how I would update the 'split' row

Comment: Can you rephrase your question a litle bit ?

Comment: ok... ill asked a shorter question (the bit which I don't think I can figure out). How to order a result set (by anything) and then update the first 10 rows to have '1' in the split column, the next 10 to have '2', next 10 '3'...etc

Comment: Is page_id in tblOne your primary key (i.e is there any duplicate page_id in tblOne ?)

Comment: yes... page_id is a primary_id in tblOne... and a view_id is the primary key in tblMany

Comment: Is all your page_id into tblMany also in tblOne ? If not what happens to your tblOne order when they are not into tblMany ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the distinct page id and their count ordered by page_id count in descendant order (so max count first) :

```
SELECT page_id, count(1) 
FROM tblMany 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

So for a tblMany like this:

```
view_id | page_id
--------+---------
  1         1
  2         1
  3         2
  4         2
  5         2
  6         3
```

You will get

```
 page_id | count(1)
 --------+---------
    2        3
    1        2
    3        1
```

Comment: That part works a treat... I guess I can use PHP to get num_rows. divide that by 5 then use limit to get chunks of the result set... then update each of the rows in the result set according to their chunk